# how to copy a file from data/data/(some_name) to a raw folder?

Tags: android

I have a file stored in /data/data/some_name/a.xml. How to copy this file from there to a raw folder as i need to parse this file.
I found this answer [how to copy a file stored in /data/data/com.sai.myproj/files/a.txt to res folder in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027636/how-to-copy-a-file-stored-in-data-data-com-sai-myproj-files-a-txt-to-res-folder) ,  but it did not solve my problem.

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot copy a file to resources of a built Android application. Resources are compiled and packed when the application is built and cannot be altered later.

Comment: I tried to push the file onto the device from Android device monitor but i got "Failed to push selection: Local path doesn't exist." I don't know what i can do more? any idea?

Comment: Where did you try to push it?

Comment: I did it wrong. I used "push", but it is correct using "pull"(adb pull) from the device to the res/raw folder. I think so. I can't update automatically the file from the download folder, i have to do it manually (using adb pull) or there is another method?

Comment: In that case the error message means the local path (where to pull to) is incorrect and you need to provide a correct path. The download folder? It depends. If it is inside `/data/data`, you cannot access it in any other way but if it is the standard download folder `/sdcard/Download`, you can mount it to your computer over USB cable.

Comment: I used after that like i said the "adb pull" and it went well. Any suggestions how i can update the file in the raw folder automatically without to pull it again manually?